# Firebase analytics not providing logged events from all users

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, firebase-analytics

We currently have about 10,000 android devices of those 10,000. About 8,800 of those devices are running Android 7.1.1. On two of the eight applications installed on these devices, we decided to use firebase analytics to be able to collect useful data about how users are using our applications.

Upon looking at the data that was collected in the first week. App_open, a number of events that are being logged from the device. The results did not seem reflective of our user base.

The number of users who had information being logged was roughly about 800 users.

Its should be noted that we do not use the google play store to release and update our application and use the device manufacturer's store to upload and update the applications on these devices.

I know that the information that is collected or logged from the device is cached and posted by google play services.

However, I cannot seem to find a reason why there is such a great disparity in actual and expected results. I was expecting feedback from roughly 8,800 devices.

Comment: I am not sure about this, I blv, the analytics data is not synced in real time, rather, it takes days, maybe weeks to reach in your console.

Comment: @theapache64 I do know that the data is sent to the console after every hour if there is anything to send

Comment: Are you sure that all 10,000 devices was updated to the latest version with analytics? how many daily active users you have?

Comment: @PavelPoley I cannot guarantee that all 10,000 devices were updated to the latest version of google play services.

Answer (score 0):

There are few reasons:

- 10k devices doesn't mean that they use your app, according to [this](http://info.localytics.com/blog/mobile-apps-whats-a-good-retention-rate) article apps have in **average** 29% retention rate within 90 days but it can be much lower(from my experience it can be less then 2%), so in fact at least 70% of users not using your app.
- The users that use your app doesn't updated to latest version with analytics.

Also you need to keep in mind that 800 users some of them are **new** users that just downloaded the app, firebase analytics show all the statistics so in few weeks you will see your retention rate.